# Extract all hrefs from an HTML url

Tags: php, parsing, extract

I want to extract all hrefs  from:

https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/

and add to a foreach loop.

I've tried using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

But it just times out....
Any help would be appreciated.
here is my code:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

**OR
Using Object orient way:**

```
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a URL 
$html->load_file('https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: You ought to add the code that you have tried

Comment: Why not use regular expression

Comment: "time out"  may  because of the html content is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved your issue please use this code will help you better**

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://niraj140792.wordpress.com/');
//Create a new DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link){
    //Extract and show the "href" attribute.
    echo $link->nodeValue;
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: and does this work with the given url in the question?

Comment: yes ofcourse working just checked...but why you are downvoting this

Comment: Just have to ask... if I might.. I know this is a new question I guess.. But if I only wanted to grab olny urls of prefix "wp-"

Comment: sure feel free to ask

Comment: sure replace this line in code by
 if (strpos($link->getAttribute('href'), 'wp-') !== false) {
      echo $link->nodeValue;
      echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br>';
    }

Comment: I didn't downvote it at all @Nirajpatel - I simply asked if it worked because it timed out for me.

Comment: ok no issue man....just improving myself as well as share knowledge i have to help required persons